# 30% CPU usage when charger unplugged. When plugged in, cpu usage drops to 2%

Tags: battery, android, cpu-usage, debug, smartphone

I have checked by external debugger and it seems that `batteryservice:update start` runs 10 times per second. Other battery processes are running very often too, only with charger unplugged. It's brand new Samsung GT-S7562. What can cause this? Is there any chance to repair it on warranty rules or should I send back to seller?

edit: I have locked cpu frequency to max and noticed no changes in cpu usage. Also checked for frequency decreasing when charger unpluged and see no association with this action.

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party tools installed? Maybe it's enough to restore factory defaults?
It's also possible that the cpu frequency is extremely low to save energy, so it might really be 30% usage, but at 100 Mhz for example.

Comment: I've tried with restore factory defaults, and then unistall all i can from aplication manager. Don't makes any difference. Power saving is OFF. I will try to toggle power saving OFF and ON and make some LogCat reading. Then i will try to lock cpu frequency and try new LogCat reading. But i think it's something else because on other smartphones connecting charger don't make any difference on cpu usage. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe it's set to have different speeds, while on battery and ehile plugged in. Like @davidbaumann said